# AFNetworking - POST Method with JSON parameter: var = {JSON}

Tags: ios, json, post, parameters, afnetworking

I'm using a webservice that accepts POST method like this

KEY  d
; VALUE    {JSON REQUEST}

for example (login):

> d={ "action": [ "login" ], "request_data": { "login": { "user":
>   "user", "password": "password" } } }

If I use AFHTTPClient the server doesn't find any "d" parameter. I've tried to create dictionaries with all parameters, serialize via NSJSONSERIALIZE and then wrap everything in a NSMutabliDictionary *parmas with key-value @"d", params to pass to [httpClient postPath[....] ] but with no success.
How can I do?

Answer (score 0):

```
NSString *jsonString  = @"YourStringFromServer";
NSDictionary *temDic = [jsonString JSONValue]; // convert string Value to JSON and add it to Dictionary.
NSlog(@"%@",temDic);// set specific key for specific value.
```

Answer (score 0):

It's looking for a JSON string.  I'm having a bit of trouble understanding the last couple of sentences in your question (you're not describing the steps very clearly) but basically:

```
//Create your params
NSDictionary *parametersDictionary = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                                                                    yourData, @"action",
                                                                    someMoreData, @"request_data", nil];

NSString *parametersJSONString = [parametersDictionary JSONString];

NSDictionary *parametersToSend = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:parametersJSONString forKey:@"d"];
```

And you should be good to go. Note that `JSONString` requires JSONKit. Also, debug/log `parametersToSend` before sending to make sure you've got the correct data and that the problem doesn't lie elsewhere.

Comment: nope, i always get missing parameters from server but if I build an NSURLRequest with same dictionary it works. Something goes wrong with AFHTTPClient and postPath method. So I build a NSURLRequest and alloc a AFHTTPRequestOperation with it.

Comment: Are you building an `NSURLRequest` object or an `NSMutableURLRequest` object?